# Why Can't I register my android device? xam.pushnotification

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using xam.plugin.pushnotification in my xamarin.forms project

my main activity

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        //inicializa imageCircle
        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

        //inicializa o mapa
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        //shared Preferences
        App.Init(new AndroidUserPreferences());

        //Gerenciador de memória
        CachedImageRenderer.Init();

        try
        {
            AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;
            CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>("my sender");
            StartPushService();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var s = e.Message;
        }

        AndroidUserPreferences sharedPref = new AndroidUserPreferences();
        if ( sharedPref.GetString("token") == " ")
        {
            GetTokenTask myTask = new GetTokenTask();
            myTask.Execute(this);
        }

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public static void StartPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {

            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }
```

My listener in my pcl

```cs
public class  CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
{

    public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Message Arrived");
    }

    public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Push Notification - Device Registered - Token : {0}", token));
    }

    public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Push Notification - Device Unnregistered");

    }

    public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Push notification error - {0}",message));
    }

    public bool ShouldShowNotification()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Registering (trying LOL) in app.cs (PCL)

```cs
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Splash2());
    }
```

I registered my project in firebase using the package name, then I created a project there and getted the sender ID...BUT...
after call "cross...current.register()", somewhere (it doesn't show me where), I have a exception

> FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100005a (from typeref, class/assembly Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid.InstanceID, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)

do i need to install xamarin.gcm in my pcl project? now it is only in my android project

Comment: I´am using Xam.Plugin.PushNotification-hig. Please, try this nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `CrossPushNotification.Current.Register ();` into `OnCreate` method. Like this:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    //inicializa imageCircle
    ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

    //inicializa o mapa
    global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

    //shared Preferences
    App.Init(new AndroidUserPreferences());

    //Gerenciador de memória
    CachedImageRenderer.Init();

    try
    {
        AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;
        CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>("my sender");
        //call register method here
        CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
        StartPushService();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var s = e.Message;
    }

    AndroidUserPreferences sharedPref = new AndroidUserPreferences();
    if ( sharedPref.GetString("token") == " ")
    {
        GetTokenTask myTask = new GetTokenTask();
        myTask.Execute(this);
    }

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to migrate to 1.2.5-beta too, it does work, BUT the plugin was recently announced as [DEPRECATED](https://github.com/BDBPayroll/xamarin-plugins/blob/master/PushNotification/README.md).
Thats bad news.

In order to support monoandroid80 I had to fork xam.plugin.pushnotification and update its packages.config manually.

There soon would be no other choice but to migrate.